# Meaning of chain of guards in religious interpretation in Kafka's parable of the law

Tags: franz-kafka, the-trial

> Well, he does discover something: namely that this door was meant for him and him alone. What does the ‘law’ and this special exclusive ‘door’ represent? As so often with Kafka’s writing, a religious interpretation seems likely. After all, in The Trial, it is a priest who tells the parable to Josef K.
>
> Those wishing to understand God, represented here as a ‘law’, are ready to devote their lives to him and want to get to know God in some deeper sense. But they are always kept out from God, and are not meant to understand him fully in this life. As the Bible famously says, in 1 Corinthians 13:12:
>
> For now we see through a glass, darkly; but then face to face: now I know in part; but then shall I know even as also I am known
>
> -[Refer](https://interestingliterature.com/2021/08/franz-kafka-before-the-law-summary-analysis/)

Suppose one takes this interpretation seriously, then what does the chain of guards mean? The outermost guard tell Kafka, that there exist guards inside who are protecting more doors and so on.

Comment: I don't see any reference to a 'chain of guards'.

Comment: In the beginning he says that behind the gaurd, there is another gaurd stronger and so on forever @KateBunting

Comment: Note that Kafka was Jewish, not Christian:   (Jewish religious law) is an endless chain of increasing depth and detail, that can be studied an entire lifetime.